# Javascript always returns float numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, integer, decimal, tofixed

Thats my jquery code. And the variable "procenti" always return like 92.3076923076923 % long decimal number. I would like that number to be without the decimals, only 92%. I tried .toFixed() method but it doesnt works.

When the equation is like procenti=(3/10)*100; == 30%, the number in html looks just what i want without decimals.

```
for(var i=1; i<14; i++){

  var zmage=parseFloat($('#zm'+i).text());
  var odigrane=parseFloat($('#od'+i).text());
  var procenti=0;


  if(zmage == 0){
      $('#pr'+(i)).html(0 + ' %');
  }
  else{
      procenti=(zmage/odigrane)*100;
      $('#pr'+(i)).text(procenti + ' %');
  }

  }
```

Comment: instead use `parseInt(int, 10)`.

Comment: `.text(procenti.toFixed(0) + ' %')`

Comment: i figured it out, i used Math.round() and it works :)

Comment: thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**round()** function will round off value.

```
Math.round(procenti);
```

Otherwise there are another functions **ceil()** & **floor()**

Answer (score 1):

You should use either

```
Math.floor()
```

It returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

or

```
Math.ceil()
```

It returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a given number.

or

```
Math.round()
```

It returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

It depends on what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function strip(number) {
return (parseFloat(number).toPrecision(12));
```

}

Hope this helps && pozdrav iz Velenja! :)