# Obtain two decimal places in JavaScript without rounding to the next bigger number

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this JS code:

```
var propertyYield = annualRent / propertyValue * 100.0;
```

In specific scenario the result is 4.999.

So when I do this

> propertyYield.toFixed(2)

I'm getting propertyYield of 5.00.

What I want to achieve is to actually get 4.99 instead of 5.00 as rounding to two decimals.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Check this thread which have similar problem statement http://stackoverflow.com/a/4912870/4948688

Comment: Please check the article already discussed.
[Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526389/javascript-always-returns-float-numbers/38526459#38526459)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Math.floor and some additional arithmetics:

```
Math.floor(15.7784514000 * 100) / 100
```

Or convert the number into a string, match the number up to the second decimal place and turn it back into a number:

```
Number(15.7784514000.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/))
```

Then you can still call toFixed to get a string with a fixed number of decimal places.

```js
var num1 = Math.floor(15.7784514000 * 100) / 100;
console.log(num1);

var num2 = Number(15.7784514000.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/));
console.log(num2)
console.log(num2.toFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: As noted by @kuka this does not work for certain decimal numbers due to floating point error math. Don't use this solution - However I'm leaving it here for documentation sake.

Not sure if I know a library method off hand to do that but quick simple old school solution would be this:

```
Math.floor(4.999 * 100) / 100.0
```

Comment: Good call! Nice catch!